# What word should I use?

Tags: word-request

Simply, I just want to know antonym of "causative factor"

Below is the background the reason I wonder.

Normally, cell is connected with collagen.

When cell is detached from collagen, cell will be dead.
-> In this case, cell detachment is a causative factor of cell death.
Reversly, when cell is dead, cell will be detached from collagen.
-> In this case, cell detachment result from cell death.

Here is my question.

To determine whether cell detachment is a causative factor or "____ factor" of cell death.

What word should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop the word 'factor' and use [consequence](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/consequence) or [implication](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/implication):

> To determine whether cell detachment is a causative factor or *a consequence* / *an implication* of cell death

The word [factor](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/factor_1) already has some part of the 'causative' in it:

> one of several things that cause or influence something